# Populating Entities list into an dropdown on HTML page load using web api

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, forms

I am trying to load all the available entities in the CRM, using web api and I am able to fetch all the required information.

```
URL/api/data/v8.0/EntityDefinitions?$select=SchemaName,LogicalName,IsValidForAdvancedFind&$filter=IsValidForAdvancedFind eq true
```

But, not able to populate the dropdown, on the page load (It is a **HTML Page**). Please help me how can I achieve that?

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectEntity"); 
for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++)
{
  var opt = results.value[i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt["SchemaName"];
  el.value = opt["LogicalName"];
  select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to dynamically add options to an existing select in vanilla javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730621/how-to-dynamically-add-options-to-an-existing-select-in-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: May be change textContent into text, it should work..

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the syntax for dropdown `text` assignment.

```
el.text = opt["SchemaName"];
```