# The 'add' method of input elements

Tags: javascript

I've struggled to find the documentation for the `add()` method that's called to add `Option`s to input elements.

I've looked on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#methods), but can't see it there or in the parent interfaces either. I was just wondering where I could find it, or what the 2nd parameter was for.

Eg:

```
const select = document.querySelector('.select-element');
const option = new Option(name, id);
select.add(option, undefined);
```

Comment: a) you find the methods of inputs on MDN's [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) page, not on the [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) one b) it's not an input but rather a [`select` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), which does have an [`add` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730621/how-to-dynamically-add-options-to-an-existing-select-in-vanilla-javascript)

[Documentation for the `add` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add)

```
// get selector element
var daySelect = document.getElementById("myDaySelect");
// create new option
var myOption = document.createElement("option");
myOption.text = "test";
myOption.value = "value";
// add new option
daySelect.add(myOption);
```

Comment: Hi Dean, sorry, I meant the function to add a select option to a select input. I've added an example above.

Comment: @NickW see my answer.