# JS: fiddle for creating dynamic select fails under IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, jsfiddle

I was recently reading this old SO question: [Dynamically add input type select with options in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340644/dynamically-add-input-type-select-with-options-in-javascript)

about dynamically creating the options for a <select> element. I understand that issue and think Chandu's answer is fine.

I took the JSFiddle of the OP and Chandu's answer and forked that into a JS Fiddle of my own that seems to work fine under Chrome (updated yesterday) and Firefox (52.6.0):  http://jsfiddle.net/h1cg7ncy/2/

But that fiddle seems to fail under IE 11.

The IE console is showing: `'addinput' is undefined`

I guess there is something about the way IE does things that I'm not understanding.

My question is: "How can this jsFiddle be fixed so that it works the same under Chrome, Firefox and IE11?"

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty simple. It appears the code uses ES6 features and IE11 does not support it.

Comment: Try to replace the template literals with sting concatenation.

Comment: That seems to be correct. Thanks epascarello and Titus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Template literals: EG ` are not valid JavaScript under IE11.
[About Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)